# Use a different translation in the same language depending on the Route - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**Problem:**

Use a different translation in the same language depending on the Route with Laravel.

I need to have, in the same language, two different translations, depending on the Route I'm using.

**Solution I managed**

This worked for me.

lang\pt\resid.php

```
   $array = [
      "hello" => "ola",
      "bye" => "adeus"
   ];

   $route = Route::current()->uri();

   if($route == "pt/resid/formRequestResid/create" || $route == "pt/resid/formDropResid/create"){

       $array['create'] = 'Submeter Pedido';
   }

else{

       $array['create'] = 'Criar';
   }

   return $array;
```

*Comments*

Is there a better way to do this?

Meanwhile hope this can help somebody with the same problem.

Comment: Do you have a different view for every route?

Comment: I am bit confused ! Any how for globalization ( supporting multiple language translation) you need to use the Resource files and Language code as Resource.resx  or Resource.En-Us.resx   No need translate based on routing.

Answer (score 0):

In your language file, I would suggest a similar structure:

```
return [
    'create' => [
        'route-1' => 'some text',
        'route-2' => 'other text',
    ];
];
```

The logic could be like so:

```
trans('lang_file.create.'.$route_name);
```